# Play + AngularJS + HTML5Mode

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0, angular-ui-router

I am setting up a Play Framework 2.3 server and would like to use AngularJS + ui-router without hashbang URLs. Routing obviously works fine as long as I use hashbang URLs, but I cannot get html5mode to work. Play always shows me a 404. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it to work:

(I am using play-yeoman)

```
GET     /                controllers.Yeoman.index(name="")
GET     /results         controllers.Yeoman.any
GET     /results/*any   controllers.Yeoman.routing(any)
->      /                yeoman.Routes

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

and:

```
object Yeoman extends Controller {

  def index = Action.async {
    request =>
          Assets.at("index.html").apply(request)
  }
  def any = Action.async {
    request =>
      Assets.at("index.html").apply(request)
  }
  def routing(path:String) = Action.async {
    request =>
      Assets.at("index.html").apply(request)
  }
}
```

So angular.js takes care of the routing past /results. It is also taking care of the /results path, but if I use /*any it messes up my other routings. Hope it helps!

Comment: This question might be helpful to anyone looking for play 2.5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495163/angular-html5mode-playframework-gives-404-when-refreshed/42495164#42495164