# Angular Html5Mode PlayFramework gives 404 when refreshed

Tags: playframework, angular2-routing, playframework-2.5

I am setting up a `Play Framework 2.5` server to use `Angular`'s SPA(single page App) approach and would like to use `PathLocationStrategy` that removes the HashTags(`#example`)

The page loads fine when I first hit the server, but if I refresh or come back after bookmarking it, gives `404`

In the Angular [documentation for Angular Router](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) it states that server side configuration is required

There's lots of info on how to do this using `nginx` or `apache` but how does one do it in Play without a proxy infront?

Here's my angular router configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'main',
        component: JobsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'job-details',
        component: JobDetailsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'job-submit',
        component: JobSubmitComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/main',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/main',
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Play `routes.conf`

```
GET     /    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is when angular changes the URL bar to `/main`, your server is not involved. If you press refresh, the browser will request `/main` which it will not find.

Your best approach is to make a route that will catch the desired routes and have it send it back to the index. Here's an example

#### Make the route to catch the requests:

Can also be a regex as per the [Play 2.5 documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#The-URI-pattern)

```
# Place at the bottom of your routes.conf to be checked last
GET     /*anyUrl     controllers.CatchAllController.catchAll(anyUrl)
```

#### Make the controller

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class CatchAllController extends Controller{
    def catchAll(anyUrl: String) = Action.async { request =>
        Assets.at("/public", "index.html").apply(request)
    }
}
```

All links/refreshes should work as intended, no proxy required